# Many-to-many relationships within GraphQL Apollo

Tags: node.js, express, graphql, sequelize.js, apollo

As I start to flesh out my first GraphQL backend, I'm running into an issue with how to handle Many-to-Many models in schemas and resolvers whenever pivot tables are needed.

Say I have Users and Teams. Each of them belongsToMany in a pivot table called UserTeam. The question is how best to handle the data flow with resolvers.

Now I could handle this by creating a schema for the pivot table and connecting the resolver relationships to that. But it seems so messy. If I do that, queries will end up such as:

```
query{
    user(ID: "1"){
        userTeams(){
            team{
                name
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now there has to be a better way to do this. I just don't know what it 
is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sequelize supports [belongsToMany](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/associations.html#belongs-to-many-associations) associations that allow you to query the associated model *through* another table/model. This is what's commonly used for M2M relationships, at least when you don't need any data from the pivot table itself. For example defining a relationship like:

```
User.belongsToMany(Team, {through: 'UserTeam'})
```

will let you call the appropriate method on a returned instance:

```
user.getTeams()
```

Similarly, associated models may be *included* when using a find method:

```
User.findOne({ include:[Team] })
```

See the docs more details.

Answer (score 1):

Query will/should be a bit simpler:

```
query{
  user(ID: "1"){
    userTeams {
      name
    }
  }
}
```

because `userTeams` will be (resolver should return) an array of `team` type.

Seems less messy?